# How can I Insert data from code to Db and create POST method

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, webapi

**Entity framework**
I have to insert the data from code to Db and I have to create POST method. For this I have made the Employee controller but I am getting some error in code. This is my code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using VENUS.HRMS.DATA.Models;

namespace VENUS.HRMS.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public TblEmployee InsertTblEmployee(TblEmployee _tblemployee)
        {
            using (TblEmployeesEntities entities = new TblEmployeesEntities())
            {
                entities.TblEmployees.Add(_tblemployee);
                entities.SaveChanges();
            }

            return _tblemployee;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error on TblEmployeesEntities entities = new TblEmployeesEntities.
Please help me out.

Comment: What is exactly the error that you get?? Which version of .net  do you use?

Comment: I am getting the error CS0246. I am using .net5

Comment: Could you please put your DBcontext source code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this sample code could help you. Write your DBcontext like below:

```
public partial class TblEmployeesEntities : DbContext
    {
        public TblEmployeesEntities ()
        { }
        public TblEmployeesEntities (DbContextOptions<TblEmployeesEntities> options)
            : base(options)
        { }
        public virtual DbSet<TblEmployee> TblEmployees{ get; set; }
    }
```

Then it's time to inject dbcontext in the startup if your DBMS is SQL server.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<TblEmployeesEntities >(options =>   
    options.UseSqlServer("ConnectionString"));

            
        }
```

Now just create a constructor in the controller and use DbContext:

```
private readonly TblEmployeesEntities _context;

public EmployeeController (TblEmployeesEntities context)
{
    _context = context;
}
[HttpPost]
public TblEmployee InsertTblEmployee(TblEmployee _tblemployee)
{
        _context.TblEmployees.Add(_tblemployee);
        _context.SaveChanges();

    return _tblemployee;
}
```

Comment: Which controller I have to use ? I mean MVC or API controller?

Comment: should I add something in Data folder too??

Comment: The controller that you have already created is true, you don't need anything more. But you need to install some packages and also make migration if you haven't done that already

Comment: when I am testing my application it's giving me ERROR404

Comment: it's the same u have given me

Comment: there is no more error in the code now but its giving 404 ERROR

Comment: This is a good tutorial on microsoft.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio have a look and see if it is ok.

Comment: How do you call your api?

Comment: if this is .net3.1, then the process will change??

Comment: I mean the URL that you use for your request

Comment: if this is .net3.1, then the process will change?? No.

Comment: Is there any problem in class namespace reference…??

Comment: Url should be this: http://0.0.0.0:44392/api/employee .And dont forget to use post method in postman.

Comment: {
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|3a0dc11a-490dba64c347fc8d.",
    "errors": {
        "$.StartDate": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTime. Path: $.StartDate | LineNumber: 6 | BytePositionInLine: 26."
        ]
    }
}

Comment: Put your request body and also TblEmployee model to see what is the problem.

Comment: System.ArgumentException: 'Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.'
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    VENUS.HRMS.API.Controllers.EmployeeController.InsertTblEmployee(VENUS.HRMS.DATA.Models.TblEmployee) in EmployeeController.cs
    [External Code]
this is the error I am getting now